# svn import error: unable to connect to a repository at URL

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I'm using ubuntu and I'm following basic tutorial about how to use svn.

I followed the instructions in the book but it shows error when I try to import after I created a repository.

Here are my screenshot of what I've done.

[image]

Can you help me and tell me what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file://` URL you enter is incorrect because it's incomplete. You have to specify the full path to the repository on your local filesystem since you access the repository directly. So in your case the URL will be as in this command-line:

`svn import ./likeU file:///home/seoyoung/repository`

Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html)!